# In VSTS, how can I set default backlog columns?

Tags: azure-devops

In our project, we've deemed certain fields pointless while adding others that have more value to us, and unfortunately some of the default columns include fields that have no value to us.

Per documentation, column options can only be changed by the user... I'm hoping there's another way, because we are planning to onboard ~75 people, many of which are non-technical and have never used VSTS before.

Can I change the default column options in the backlog?

Or is there a way I can automate it for each user? The REST API seems to only allow reads.

Comment: PS I know I can set column options on queries.  That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "columns"? Are you talking about configuring the columns on the backlog? Or are you talking about removing individual fields  on a given type of work item (e.g. task, user story, bug, etc)?

Comment: @DanielMann Configuring columns on the backlog

Comment: Backlog column configuration is on a per-team basis, not per-user basis.

Comment: @emragins have you found the solution please?

Comment: @MartinHaluza No, though I never tried Andy's answer, below.  Other items ended up taking priority.  If his answer works for you, please let me know so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a way to set default backlog columns in the template.

However, based on my test, the REST API works to update the column options for a specific backlog.

```
POST https://your-account.visualstudio.com/_api/_webSettings/setString?__v=5
```

[image]

Comment: Will this update the columns for all users? Is this API documented? I can't find it in the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: tried a bunch of difference combinations to try and get the "webSettings", but always got a 404. i did find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogconfiguration/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 that has `columnFields`, but they do not provide a PUT, POST or PATCH to change the column fields.